# Why does the Stevenson Award show "Sheldon Cooper Ph.D." when he got his Ph.D. at 16?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-big-bang-theory

In the Episode of **The Big Bang Theory**,  ***The Cooper-Hofstadter Polarization***, Leonard mentions that Sheldon got his Ph.D. at the age of 16.

However in the episode of **The Jerusalem Duality**, Sheldon mentions that he got the Stevenson award at the age of 14 and a half.

So, why does this award mention Sheldon Lee Cooper, Ph.D. as he got his Ph.D. at the age of 16?

Here is a screenshot. (though I could not get the clear one.)

[image]

Comment: I watched this episode multiple times, but I got my eyes on it this time. By the way, he got two doctorates and one Sc.D. Probably Leonard was referencing one of them.

Comment: With any authority? Maybe if someone tweets the production.

Comment: To be honest I can't even see where it's mentioned on award.

Comment: @Rahul It's in the image. I'll try to get a better picture.

Comment: @AJ: I tried looking up in **The Jerusalem Duality** but it's not clear. Might be you can get it from another episode.

Comment: @Rahul Hmm. I'll try. However, you can also add more details to your answer like possibilities or something instead of only mentioning it being a plot mistake. :)

Answer (score 7):

Quoting from [Wikia](http://bigbangtheory.wikia.com/wiki/California_Institute_of_Technology):

> The room also has Sheldon's Stevenson Award, framed near the door inside (the certificate is signed incorrectly Sheldon Lee Cooper, Ph.D., as he had not yet received a doctorate when he was the recipient).

So that seems to be a mistake.